# Reading out dice

Tags: c#

We need to make some small program for school that rolls 5 dices and see if you get a three of a kind with it, if so, increase points etc.

The problem isnt to reading out the dice, I have the knowledge to get it done, but I want it to be a little efficient, not a ugly piece of code that takes up half a page. I have found ways to filter out the the duplicates in an array, but not the other way around. It rolls with 5 dices, so its an array with 5 numbers, is there like a built in function or a nice, efficient way of returning the number that has been rolled three times or return null if none of the number are rolled three times?

Hope anyone can push me in the right direction. :)

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you are not asking us to do your homework for you, but you should post your code as it is currently.

Comment: What have you tried so far that you're not happy with? For homework questions especially, you need to post what you've tried so far, explain how it's not working as you'd like, and ask specific questions. Please post your current code, and ask questions about actual parts of that code. (And for schoolwork, you should include the `homework` tag.) It is good, though, that you're not asking to have the code written for you. Thanks. :)

Comment: For an answer that works and is one line of code, see the lambda version of the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655759/how-to-get-the-most-common-value-in-an-int-array-c Not the most efficient way, though...

Comment: You can do this in one line (several methods) with Linq, but even without Linq, a handrolled function is just a few lines of code. Take some more time and see if you're writing too much.

Comment: The thing is that I dont realy have code now, i've been fiddling around with it untill it was completely broken. But i can recreate it if it helps. It was a for loop that loops 5 times, with 6 if statements in it that looked for 1 through 6 and did one++; or two++; etcEDIT:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to store a 6-element array containing the *count* of how many dice have that face. Loop through the 5 dice and increment the appropriate face's total count.

```
var rolls = new List<Roll>();
// run as many rolls as you want. e.g.:
rolls.Add(new Roll(5));
var threeOfAKindRolls = rolls.Where(r => r.HasThreeOfAKind());

public class Roll
{
     public Roll( int diceCount )
     {
          // Do your random generation here for the number of dice

         DiceResults = new int[0]; // your results.
         ResultCounts = new int[6]; // assuming 6 sided die

         foreach (var diceResult in DiceResults)
         {
             ResultCounts[diceResult]++;
         }
     }

     public int[] DiceResults { get; private set; }

     public int[] ResultCounts { get; private set; }

     public bool HasThreeOfAKind()
     {
         return ResultCounts.Any(count => count >= 3);
     }
}
```

This code can be shortened somewhat if you don't need the result counts to perform other tests on the results:

```
     public Roll( int diceCount )
     {
          // Do your random generation here for the number of dice
         DiceResults = new int[0]; // your results.
     }

     public bool HasThreeOfAKind()
     {
         ResultCounts = new int[6]; // assuming 6 sided die
         foreach (var diceResult in DiceResults)
         {
             // Increment and shortcut if the previous value was 2
             if( (ResultCounts[diceResult]++) == 2) return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
```

Comment: I can't speak for the downvoter, but we usually consider it poor form to provide 100% working code in response to homework problems.

Comment: Joke is on you, @sarnold! This isn't working code! Tyson, note that an array of counts for a six-sided die will be indexed 0-5, meanwhile the rolls will presumably be generated as 1-6. Off by one error in the result, lest it is preceded by index out of range exception. I also see a zero length array, although there appears to be some collaborative/competing editing going on.

Comment: Point taken @sarnold, I'll remember that in future.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, good pick up... or was that part of my grand plan to teach him some debugging skills...???

Comment: Its a bit to complicated for the level we are schooled for, but i can definitely use this. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily and succinctly with LINQ:

```
var diceRolls = new[] {1, 3, 3, 3, 4};
var winningRolls = diceRolls.GroupBy(die => die).Select(groupedRoll => new {DiceNumber = groupedRoll.Key, Count = groupedRoll.Count()}).Where(x => x.Count >= 3).ToList();
```

What this is doing is grouping the rolls by the roll number ("Key") and the count of occurrences of that roll. Then, it's selecting any rolls that have a count greater than or equal to 3. The result will be a `List` containing your winning rolls.

Answer (score 1):

Given what you are describing your answer as looking like it sounds like you're trying to do a massive comparison.  That's the wrong approach.

Pretend it's 20 dice rather than 5, a good answer will work just as well in a larger case.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like the following:

```
public int? WinningRoll(IEnumerable<int> rolls)
{
    int threshold = rolls.Count() / 2;

    var topRollGroup = rolls.GroupBy(r => r)
        .SingleOrDefault(rg => rg.Count() > threshold);

    if (topRollGroup != null)
        return topRollGroup.Key;

    return null;
}
```

This will work with any number of rolls, not just 5, so if you had 10 rolls, if 6 of them were the same value, that value would be returned. If there is no winning roll, null is returned.