# Determine the most common elements in an int array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

The questions on here I have found about this have the answer only returning one of the most common elements.

I have an int[10] filled with random numbers (between 0 and 20), and I need to find the mode. But being random, sometimes there is more than one mode, and sometimes there is none.

Currently my code for finding the mode is:

```
int mode = numArray.GroupBy(v => v)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .Key;
```

which this works fantastically, but if say 12 and 8 both appear most commonly, it only shows one of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the most common value in an Int array? (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655759/how-to-get-the-most-common-value-in-an-int-array-c)

Comment: I've checked over those answers before asking this one, they all only gave one of the most common, not all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't like the code, but think that's the most effective way:

```
int temp = -1;
var mode = numArray.GroupBy(v => v)
                   .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                   .TakeWhile(g => {
                         if(temp == -1)
                             temp = g.Count();
                         return temp == g.Count(); })
                   .Select(g => g.Key)
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: `int mode =` ... `.ToArray()` ?

Comment: @ClickRick Updated. Nice catch.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: I think *grouping twice* is effective, and leads to much cleaner code. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

```
var groups = numArray.GroupBy(v => v)
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                .ToList();

IEnumerable<int> modes = groups.TakeWhile(g => g.Count() == groups.First().Count())
                               .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: Calling `groups.First()` inside `TakeWhile` will cause entire query to be run over and over again (grouping and ordering). You should store it in temp variable.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - I'll add "ToList()" which will cause it to only be used once. True, it will cause the container to be stored in memory, but it will be simpler code. This is a simplicity over performance tradeoff.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd: If you're aiming for simpler code, a double-grouping is the cleaner way to go...

Answer (score 3):

A (perhaps) more elegant approach involves grouping twice, once by value, and then by count:

```
var modes = numArray.GroupBy(i => i)
    .GroupBy(numGroup => numGroup.Count(), numGroup => numGroup.Key)
    .OrderByDescending(supergroup => supergroup.Key)
    .First().ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 Certainly the least code, but it turned my brain into knots reading it :-)

Comment: @AndrewShepherd: I'll take that as a compliment! :) Ok, maybe it's not the *most* readable - but IMO you're likely to have fewer bugs if the final code involves only inbuilt operations (such as Grouping) rather than custom-written comparison logic / if statements / etc.

Comment: Maybe each lambda parameter should have a different name. I get confused reading this because the type of `i` changes with each step in the chain.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd: Point taken, I've renamed the parameters for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

in done in 1 pass. Got to be better than favourite answer!

```
   public class PopularNumber
    {
        private Int32[] numbers = {5, 4, 3, 32, 6, 6, 3, 3, 2, 2, 31, 1, 32, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6};

        public PopularNumber()
        {
            Dictionary<Int32,Int32> bucket = new Dictionary<Int32,Int32>();
            Int32 maxInt = Int32.MinValue;
            Int32 maxCount = 0;
            Int32 count;

            foreach (var i in numbers)
            {
                if (bucket.TryGetValue(i, out count))
                {
                    count++;
                    bucket[i] = count;
                }
                else
                {
                    count = 1;
                    bucket.Add(i,count);
                }

                if (count >= maxCount)
                {
                    maxInt = i;
                    maxCount = count;
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",maxCount, maxInt);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int[] GetMostCommonIntegers(int[] nums)
{
    return nums
        .ToLookup(n => n)
        .ToLookup(l => l.Count(), l => l.Key)
        .OrderBy(l => l.Key)
        .Last() 
        .ToArray();
}
```

This solution can handle case when several numbers have the same number of occurences:

```
[1,4,5,7,1] => [1]
[1,1,2,2,3,4,5] => [1,2]
[6,6,6,2,2,1] => [6]
```