# Speed up working with big arrays of string in c#

Tags: c#, list

This method takes the most frequent words from string array.
It works very slowly for big arrays (like 190.000 milliseconds for 70.000 strings).
I've measured (using ***Stopwatch()***) that its first part is the slowest one:

```
public static List<WordDouble> MostFrequentWords(double count, string[] words)
    {                     
        var wordsAndNumbers = new List<WordDouble>();

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            if (wordsAndNumbers.Exists(e => e.Word == word.ToLower()))
                wordsAndNumbers[wordsAndNumbers.FindIndex(e => e.Word == word.ToLower())].Count++;
            else
            {
                var addWord = new WordDouble();
                addWord.Word = word.ToLower();
                addWord.Count = 1;
                wordsAndNumbers.Add(addWord);
            }
         }     

/*method goes on, other parts work fast and do not need improvement */
...
return something;
}

public class WordDouble
    {
        public string Word;
        public double Count;
    }
```

How can I improve performance of this method?

Comment: [CodeReview.SE] would be better place for your question.

Comment: Have you heard of a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508)?

Comment: Not that it would make a huge difference, but create a variable for the `word.ToLower()` and use that variable in the 3 places it is used

Comment: using ToLower can be improved by a word.Equals(e.Word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase); And As already mentioned use a Dictionary, you can specify the StingComparison for a dictionary aswell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655759/how-to-get-the-most-common-value-in-an-int-array-c shows code that have reasonable performance - adopting for strings should be simple as it is basic combination of GroupBy/OrderBy

Answer (score 4):

Checking for an item using `Exists` in a list is an O(n) operation, while checking for an item in a dictionary is an O(1) operation.

This runs in a fraction of the time (actually in about 1/2200 of the time):

```
Dictionary<string, int> wordsAndNumbers = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (string word in words) {
  if (wordsAndNumbers.ContainsKey(word.ToLower())) {
    wordsAndNumbers[word.ToLower()]++;
  } else {
    wordsAndNumbers.Add(word.ToLower(), 1);
  }
 }
```

Here is the result of a test run with 70000 strings, for the original code, my code, and Console's code, respectively:

```
00:01:21.0804944
00:00:00.0360415
00:00:00.1060375
```

You can even speed it up a little more by doing `ToLower` only once in the loop:

```
var wordsAndNumbers = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var word in words) {
  string s = word.ToLower();
  if (wordsAndNumbers.ContainsKey(s)) {
    wordsAndNumbers[s]++;
  } else {
    wordsAndNumbers.Add(s, 1);
  }
}
```

Test run:

```
00:00:00.0235761
```

Comment: i think you should use the dictionary constructor overloads witch take a comparer instead of the frequent ToLower casts, check my answer.

Comment: @Console: Is that your reason for downvoting?

Comment: So, whoever downvoted; why? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: @Guffa you are actually right so up vote for you, but I was wondering it using PLINQ would be even faster. What do you think about approaching it with PLINQ?

Comment: @Assa: To use PLINQ each thread would create a result from a part of the words, then you would need to combine the results, which would probably eat up the gain from the first part.

Comment: @Guffa I did improve my answer it should now outperform the ToLower implementation by a bit.

Answer (score 4):

First of all why do you use a double to count words?
Use a long Dictionary and never cast to lower just for comparison.

```
Dictionary<string,long> wordsAndNumbers = new 
    Dictionary<string,long>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

foreach(var word in words)
{
    if (!wordsAndNumbers.ContainsKey(word))
        wordsAndNumbers[word] = 1;
    else
        wordsAndNumbers[word]++;
 }
```

with 70000 Words i get the following runtime: 00:00:00.0152345 which is significant faster then the to lower solution on my machine which takes 00:00:00.0320127

Comment: Using the overload of the dictionary that takes a comparer looks nice, but it's actually a lot slower. See the results in my answer.

Comment: I replaced the CurrentCultureIgnoreCase with a OridinalIgnoreCase comparer, on my machine my implementation is now by 30% faster than the tolower solution

Comment: I think that you mean `OrdinalIgnoreCase`. It's slightly faster, but I only see a 2% difference.

Comment: @Console Thank you a lot for detalied explanation. By the way it inspired me to learn about IComparer class a bit.