# Return most often present string in list

Tags: c#

I would like to return the text most often present in a list, for return in method

My list = `((EPlayersStats)x.Value).kList`

Json = `"kList": ["76561198130200574,16561198130200574,26561198130200574,36561198130200574,76561198130200574"]`

How do I proceed?

Comment: Please add the code you tried.

Comment: What do you mean by saying _the text most often present in a list_? What is the expected result from your code above?

Comment: Basically I made a list returning the IDs of the players the player killed. And I'd like to pull up the one that was killed the most.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655759/how-to-get-the-most-common-value-in-an-int-array-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do it with LINQ grouping:

```
myList.Split(',').GroupBy(s => s).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).First().Key
```

This splits on comma, turns the lot into a grouping (a mapping of each unique entry mapped to a list of all the occurrences of that entry), sorts by the number of entries in the grouping list, takes the first grouping and returns its key

```
A list of: "a,b,b,c,d,d,d"
Becomes an array: { "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d" }
Becomes a grouping:
  g["a"] = new [] { "a" } //Count 1
  g["b"] = new [] { "b", "b" } //count 2
  g["c"] = new [] { "c" } //count 1
  g["d"] = new [] { "d", "d", "d" } //count 3
Orders them by count desc (d wins)
Takes the first grouping (d)
Returns its Key ("d")
```